# How to put a parameter in a Laravel controller method not obligatory?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know how to put a parameter in a Laravel controller method not obligatory, as I've got a route like this (I'm using the ? to say it's not obligatory):

```
Route::get('/account/student/create/{student_id?}', array(
    'as' => 'account-student-create',
    'uses' => 'StudentController@getCreate'
));
```

I've got in my controller:

```
getCreate($student_id){...}
```

Put if don't fill a parameter in the route I've got a warning message:

```
Missing argument 1 for StudentController::getCreate()
```

Thanks for helping!

Jean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a default value to your controller method declaration:

```
getCreate($student_id=null){...}
```

That way when the method is called without a value, `$student_id` will be set to null.

Comment: +1 much better to set to `null` than a truthy string.

Answer (score 1):

you could write your function with a default value

```
public function getCreate($student_id = 'defaultValue')
{
    ...
}
```